# Get closest previous or future datetime to a given datetime in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get a closest Polling datetime to OrderSubmittedtime where the closest Polling datetime can be a datetime previous or future date(+ or -) compared to the OrderSubmittedtime as long as the datetime is close enough.

Below is the example for this :

```
create table Rosters
(
OrderID int,
PollingTime datetime 
,OrdersubmittedTime datetime
)    

 insert into Rosters values (1,'2017-08-07 11:30:00.000','2017-08-07 04:12:51.000')
 insert into Rosters values (1,'2017-08-07 12:13:34.000','2017-08-07 04:12:51.000')
 insert into Rosters values (1,'2017-08-07 03:30:00.000','2017-08-07 04:12:51.000')
 insert into Rosters values (1,'2017-08-08 00:30:00.000','2017-08-07 04:12:51.000')
 insert into Rosters values (2,'2017-08-05 10:30:00.000','2017-08-07 04:12:51.000')
 insert into Rosters values (2,'2017-08-06 11:30:00.000','2017-08-07 04:12:51.000')
 insert into Rosters values (2,'2017-08-08 00:30:00.000','2017-08-07 04:12:51.000')
```

[image: select * from Rosters]

expected result set is :
     for OrderID=1, the closest Polling Time will be '2017-08-07 03:30:00.000' 
and for OrderID=2, the closest Polling Time will be '2017-08-06 11:30:00.000'

i could currently get to write a query like below, but it is not correct :

```
 select PollingTime
 ,OrdersubmittedTime
 ,OrderID
, abs(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,OrdersubmittedTime,PollingTime)) as ClosestPollingTime
 from Rosters
```

Kindly help me out , Thanks.

Comment: "Close enough"? To what? What are your conditions for "close enough" to the +/- polling values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `OUTER APPLY` to join a subquery on the same table and take the closest value using your `ClosestPollingTime` like so (modified to filter on Seconds rather than minutes, based on [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45981321/get-closest-previous-or-future-datetime-to-a-given-datetime-in-sql-server/45982096#comment78924149_45982096) from [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever):

```
CREATE TABLE #Rosters
(
    OrderID INT,
    PollingTime DATETIME,
    OrdersubmittedTime DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO #Rosters
VALUES
(1, '2017-08-07 11:30:00.000', '2017-08-07 04:12:51.000'),
(1, '2017-08-07 12:13:34.000', '2017-08-07 04:12:51.000'),
(1, '2017-08-07 03:30:00.000', '2017-08-07 04:12:51.000'),
(1, '2017-08-08 00:30:00.000', '2017-08-07 04:12:51.000'),
(2, '2017-08-05 10:30:00.000', '2017-08-07 04:12:51.000'),
(2, '2017-08-06 11:30:00.000', '2017-08-07 04:12:51.000'),
(2, '2017-08-08 00:30:00.000', '2017-08-07 04:12:51.000');


SELECT r.OrdersubmittedTime,
       r.OrderID,
       t.ClosestPollingTime
FROM #Rosters AS r
    OUTER APPLY
     (
         SELECT TOP 1
             r2.OrderID,
             r2.PollingTime as ClosestPollingTime
         FROM #Rosters AS r2
         WHERE r2.OrderID = r.OrderID
         ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND, r2.OrdersubmittedTime, r2.PollingTime))
     ) t
GROUP BY r.OrdersubmittedTime,
         r.OrderID,
         t.ClosestPollingTime;

DROP TABLE #Rosters;
```

Produces:

```
OrdersubmittedTime       OrderID     ClosestPollingTime
2017-08-07 04:12:51.000  1           2017-08-07 03:30:00.000
2017-08-07 04:12:51.000  2           2017-08-06 11:30:00.000
```

Comment: Probably should use `second` rather than `minute`, since the data clearly has values granular down to the seconds. Otherwise, you could get ties within the same minute wrong and pick a further away value.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever agreed, i blindly used the `DIFF` code from the OP, will update

Comment: Thanks, Tanner, very helpful answer.It works as expected.How can I  become a coder like you?., also thanks to Damien_the_unbeliever for your valuable advice.cheers